# After insert email trigger select 1 from inserted when?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

So I have a trigger to generate an email set to fire after insert with a

`if exists (select 1 from inserted)`

clause to keep from firing if no lines are inserted.

I am wondering if there is a way to have something like:

`if exists (select 1 from inserted where Max(columnA)`

when I try to do this I just get an error

I will sometimes have multiple rows inserted where Column B-I will be the same info but Column A will be different. I want the row with the highest A to be used to generate the email.

Comment: `where Max(columnA)` *what*? What's only half a boolean clause. You also can't use aggregate functions in the `WHERE`, they go in the `HAVING`.

Comment: If you want to use the "highest A" then that has nothing to do with the `EXISTS`; but all to do with the `INSERT` within your `IF`; show us that. Provide sample data and expected results in a *consumable* format.

Comment: Side note: sending emails from a trigger is about the worst possible use of a trigger I can think.

Comment: you should use ROW_NUMBER or similar function to get the rows you're interesting in... Something like: select * from (select *, row_number() over(partition by ColumnB order by ColumnA DESC) AS sort FROM inserted ) x WHERE sort = 1